# Alternative to NULL in RDBMs

Tags: sql, database-design

What if I have a varchar field in a database which is not required? Middle name for example.

- Easy, I will just make it nullable.

But what if I want to be clear on the reasons why the data is not available?

- Then I will just put something like 'Unknown' or 'Not applicable' (Chinese?)

But what if the data type is not text? Salary for example, I can't put 'Unspecified' or 'Not applicable' (unemployed).

I could think of solutions but I want to know whether the ideas are good or bad.

1) create flag (tinyint) columns for different reasons why it is null:

```
| Salary Unspecified | Salary Not Applicable |
```

2) create a varchar column for the reason why a field is null:

```
| WhySalaryIsNotAvailable |
```

Both solutions look weird to me. I haven't seen it before so I'm not sure whether to do any of them.

How do you deal with this problem?

Is any of the solutions above okay?

Comment: Well, `null` **means** "unknown"

Comment: NULL is useful to indicate "no data here".  As to the reason why there is no data somewhere, that may be useful, generally for audit purposes.  And yeah, a tinyint shuold be able to express it well enough, with a descriptive lookup table somewhere.  As far as using the reason why data is missing in your business logic,  you should probably try to imrove your data model.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably compromise and settle on `NULL`.  It is handled throughout the database system, in comparisons and so on.

You can add the reason in another column.  For your example with names, I might be inclined to have multiple columns (including optional ones such as nickname and honorific), along perhaps with a name "format".

The particular example of name does not resonate.  I'm not sure I really know the difference between not having a middle name and a middle name not applying.

Note:  You can always include this information in another column.  But your code for comparison can start to get rather complicated.  For instance, if you put a blank (empty string) in for the middle name, but had different reasons, then:

```
on x1.middlename = x2.middlename
```

would match, unless you included the reason.

Comment: I thought Chinese don't have middle names and some didn't provide them. Now that you mention, I also think the example is bad.

Answer (score 2):

If an attribute is a string, then it is relatively easy to allow for `n/a` and `unknown`. However, the following example (design) is more general.

```
-- Employee (EMP) exists.
--
Employee {EMP}
     KEY {EMP}


-- Employee (EMP) receives regular salary.
--
SalariedEmp {EMP}
        KEY {EMP}
FOREIGN KEY {EMP} REFERENCES Employee {EMP}



-- Employee (EMP) receives salary of $ (SALARY).
--
EmployeeSalary {EMP, SALARY}
           KEY {EMP}
   FOREIGN KEY {EMP} REFERENCES SalariedEmp {EMP}



-- Employee (EMP) does not receive regular salary.
--
UnSalariedEmp {EMP}
          KEY {EMP}

-- derive as a view
CREATE VIEW UnSalariedEmp AS
SELECT EMP from Employee
EXCEPT
SELECT EMP from SalariedEmp
;
```

Comment: Should I fear joins?

Comment: @dpp, if you think of a relation as a *data type*, then `join, restrict, project ...` (their SQL equivalents) are simply operators that work on that data type. An analogy would be data type integer and operators `+,-, *, ...`. So, should we fear multiplication of integers, concatenation of strings and lists, unions and intersects of sets, etc. ?